# Overwriting existing Google spreadsheet via API (C#)

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, overwrite

I would like to overwrite an existing and shared Google spreadsheet X with an other existing Google spreadsheet Y via Drive API v3 or Scripts API from C#. Both are on my own GDrive. Since X is already shared with others, I would like to overwrite spreadsheet X by keeping its URL (and ID).

What I tried: copying sheet-by-sheet is not enough because there is a GAS script behind the spreadsheet and other metadata which is not merged by sheet-by-sheet copy. I need complete overwrite.

Thanks.

Comment: You should make some effort and provide some code .

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do a "complete overwrite" in the same sense that it could be done in several file systems.

In example, [revision history](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en) and [activity tracking](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3323935?hl=en) can not be removed.

For further details see

- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/